Change Text Color of Radzen Components: Numeric and Textbox
This should be simple, but I'm just not having any luck.  I'm trying to change the text color of a RadzenNumeric object to white.  I've tried a number of approaches.

class="rz-color-white"
Style="color: white"
style="color: white"

I'm able to change the background color using class="rz-background-color-warning", but the text color just will not change for me.  None of these options work:

<RadzenNumeric @bind-Value="numberOfCars" Name="txtNumberOfCars" ShowUpDown="false" Style="color: white" class="rz-background-color-warning"/>


<RadzenNumeric @bind-Value="numberOfCars" Name="txtNumberOfCars" ShowUpDown="false" style="color: white" class="rz-background-color-warning"/>


<RadzenNumeric @bind-Value="numberOfCars" Name="txtNumberOfCars" ShowUpDown="false"  class="rz-background-color-warning rz-color-white"/>

Looking at the Radzen site: https://blazor.radzen.com/colors?theme=material3#utility-css-classes, the last option should work.
Does anyone know how to change the text color of Radzen controls?

Add RadzenNumeric in Index.razor.
<RadzenNumeric @bind-Value="numberOfCars" Name="txtNumberOfCars" ShowUpDown="false" class="rz-background-color-warning"/>

Then add below code in app.css(or site.css).
.rz-numeric .rz-inputtext {
    color: white !important;
}

Then it will work.

